# Finding matching parentheses in a large JS file

Tags: editor

I have a ~17MB obfuscated JavaScript bundle I want to analyze. I want to find out which parenthesis ends an expression that begins right at the start of the file. I suspect that the expression spans the whole file, but I want to be sure.

I tried the go-to-matching parenthesis commands in Sublime Text, VS Code, Vim and Neovim, none of which could deal with the size of the file. Even if they could, they probably would get thrown off by mismatched parentheses in lots of Perl-style `/RegExp literals/` throughout the code. In many other languages, deleting the suspected closing paren would give an "unclosed parenthesis" error at the beginning of the expression, but Node, Bun, tsc and prettier all just report variations on "unexpected EOF" at the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Emacs did the trick. `C-M-right` and `C-M-left` to go to the beginning or the end of an expression. It just gets bricked by long lines, so I have to put the source through a prettifier first.

Why are editors like this?